# What is the extra question in [mi-yodeya-series]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

[mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) is listed as having 328 questions right now. However, the [most recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48024/shiva-veesrim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya) is 327.

What is the extra question in here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the series was up to 211 (i.e., when [210](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6382)'s answer was accepted, which was, in those days, approximately coincident with the asking of the next question in the series), it was March 20, 2011, [*Purim*](http://wwwx.uwm.edu/cgi-bin/corre/calendar/?%2B2011). In keeping with the topsy-turviness of the day, [Isaac Moses](//judaism.stackexchange.com/u/2) asked [**eleven hundred two**](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6430) next instead of **two hundred eleven**. ([211](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6483) was the next one asked after that.)